# What video driver should I install for Nvidia Corporation G96 [GeForce 9400 GT]?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, video

I have a  Nvidia video card  to enable all the compiz effects. My Ubuntu 11.10 gets slow at times or will froze. Suggestions.

Which one:

- nvidia-173
- nvidia-96
- nvidia-common
- nvidia-current
- nvidia-va-driver

Here, the data of my card:

> ubuntu 11.10 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G96
>   [GeForce 9400 GT] (rev a1)

Answer (score 1):

in "Additional Drivers" there should be shown a "recommended" NVIDIA-driver. Activate it (with working internet connection) and reboot.

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver)