# Nvidia G96 [GeForce 9400 GT] and application graphic issues

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I've got a quite old **NVIDIA** graphic card and I with installed restricted drivers from **Settings** panel (as also shown in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70652/what-video-driver-should-i-install-for-nvidia-corporation-g96-geforce-9400-gt)).

```
➜  ~  lspci
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9400 GT] (rev a1)
```

I tried a lot of them: version *173-update*, *current*, *beta*, but the only one that can run *unity-2d* it's **current-update**. That's **Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 64bit**.

However... Unity crashes, sometimes windows border disappear, Java Virtual Machine doesn't works, font rendering it's slow and so on.

How can I solve this? Some suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why downvoting? Ask for details, if you need this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same graphic card and OS version with you; this solution works fine for me:
[Install NVIDIA GeForce driver in Ubuntu 12.10 / 12.04 using PPA](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.